# TicTacToe in java

Tags: java

I have problem with this code for test this is the error [error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yg7C.jpg) [error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrNKO.jpg)

and this is the code 
first class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.List;

public class Position {
public char[] board;
public char turn;
public int dim =3;
private int l;

public Position() {
    this.board = "        ".toCharArray();
this.turn = 'x';
}
public Position(char[] board, char turn) {
this.board = board;
this.turn = turn;
}
public Position(String str) {
this.board = str.toCharArray();
this.turn = 'x';
}
public Position(String str, char turn) {
this.board = str.toCharArray();
this.turn = turn;
}

public String toString () {
return new String(board);
}

public Position move (int idx) {
char[] newBoard = board.clone();
newBoard[idx] = turn;
    return new Position(newBoard, turn == 'x' ? 'o' :'x');
}
public Integer[] possibleMoves() {
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
if (board[i] == ' ') {
list.add(i);
}
}
Integer[] array = new Integer[list.size()];
list.toArray(array);

return array;
}
public boolean win_line(char turn, int start, int step) {
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
if (board[start + step*i] != turn) {
return false;
}
}
return true;
}
public boolean win(char turn) {
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {

if (win_line(turn, i*dim, l) || win_line(turn, i,dim)) {
return true;
}
}
if (win_line(turn, dim-1, dim-1) || win_line(turn, 0, dim+1)) {
return true;
}
return false;
}
public int minimax() {
if (win('x')) { return 100; }
if (win('o')) { return -100; }
if (possibleMoves().length == 0) { return 0; }
Integer mm = null;
for (Integer idx : possibleMoves()) {
Integer value = move(idx).minimax();
if (mm == null || turn == 'x' && mm < value || turn == 'o' && value < mm) {
mm = value;
}
}
return mm + (turn == 'x' ? -1 : 1);
}
public int bestMove() {
Integer mm = null;
int best = -1;
for (Integer idx : possibleMoves()) {
Integer value = move(idx).minimax();
if (mm == null || turn == 'x' && mm < value || turn == 'o' && value < mm) {
mm = value;
best = idx;
}
}
return best;
}
public boolean gameEnd() {
return win('x') || win('o') ||  possibleMoves().length ==0;
}
}
```

Second class for test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class PositionTest {
  @Test
  public void testNew() throws Exception {
        Position position = new Position();
        assertEquals("        ", position.toString());
        assertEquals('x', position.turn);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMove() throws Exception {
    Position position = new Position().move(1);
    assertEquals(" x      ", position.toString());
        assertEquals('o', position.turn);
  }

  @Test
  public void testPossibleMoves() throws Exception {
        Position position = new Position().move(1).move(3).move(4);
        assertArrayEquals(new Integer[] {0,2,5,6,7,8}, position.possibleMoves());
  }

  @Test
  public void testWin() throws Exception {
        assertFalse(new Position().win('x'));
        assertTrue(new Position("xxx      ").win('x'));
        assertTrue(new Position("   ooo   ").win('o'));
        assertTrue(new Position("x  x  x  ").win('x'));
        assertTrue(new Position("  x x x  ").win('x'));
        assertTrue(new Position("x   x   x").win('x'));        
  }

  @Test
  public void testMinimax() throws Exception {
    assertEquals( 100, new Position("xxx      ").minimax());
    assertEquals(-100, new Position("ooo      ").minimax());
    assertEquals(   0, new Position("xoxoxooxo").minimax());
    assertEquals(  99, new Position(" xx      ").minimax());
    assertEquals( -99, new Position(" oo      ", 'o').minimax());
  }

  @Test  
  public void testBestMove() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(0, new Position(" xx      ").bestMove());
        assertEquals(1, new Position("o o      ", 'o').bestMove());
  }

  @Test
  public void testGameEnd() throws Exception {
        assertFalse(new Position().gameEnd());
        assertTrue(new Position("xxx      ").gameEnd());
  }
}
```

third class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game {
  Position position; 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java TTT");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                final Game game = new Game();
                final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
                for (int i =0; i < 9; i++) {
                  final int idx = i;   
          final JButton button = new JButton();
                  buttons[i] = button;
                  button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
                  button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                  button.setOpaque(true);
                  button.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 100));
                  button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}                      

                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
              button.setText("" + game.position.turn);
                          game.move(idx);              
              if (!game.position.gameEnd()){                      
                                int best = game.position.bestMove();
                                buttons[best].setText("" + game.position.turn);
                                game.move(best);  
                        }
                          if (game.position.gameEnd()) {
                                String message = "";  
                                if (game.position.win('x')) {
                  message = "You Won !!";             
                } else if (game.position.win('o')){
                                message = "Computer Won !!";
                                } else {
                                    message = "Draw";
                                }  
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

                        }    
                        }});
                  frame.add(button);
                }
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
          }
        });
  }
  protected void move(int idx) {
    position = position.move(idx);

  }    

}
```

> 1- java.lang.AssertionError: array lengths differed, expected.length=6
>   actual.length=5
>
> 2-java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<0> but was:<100>

Comment: Why is your indentation non existent in the first class but in the other two its fine? Edit the first class to look like the other two

Comment: As a general tip (and good practise), I would put a breakpoint somewhere in the code and step through until your assertionerror arises.

Answer (score -1):

assertionsErrors within unit testcase runs are telling you that the actual result does not fit the expected one. thus your code does not work properly and you have to fix this.

please post the lines where these errors occurr.

Comment: to the editor:
did you downvote this answer??
if so, learn to use junit and understand basic java before programming a TTT and messing up the code...
i won't play through your whole program to find your mistake if you just have to post an additional number.
it says the result is not equal to the expected value, and that's it. there `is` no error or exception, just a wrong return value...
once you understood this, you may answer this comment.